# How to make 2 actions on 1 onclick into Facebook fan page?

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-iframe

I have a poll on the Facebook iframe tab on my fan page. I want to make the feature like here facebook.com/buddymedia. If user click Submit button then poll results will display and simultaneously feed dialog will appear.

I tried this code but it did not work: 
`onclick="(return onVote(), function jsuipopup();)"`

Script for feed dialog here:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({ 
    appId:'195xxxxxxxxxxxx417', cookie:true, 
    status:true, xfbml:true 
 });
function jsuipopup(){

    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        message: ' msg here',
        name: 'name here!',
        caption: 'captn here',
        description: ( descriptn here' ),
        link: 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/mypage',
        picture: 'http://mysite.com/img/logo.png',
        actions: [{
            name: 'vote it', 
            link: 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/mypage'
        }],
        user_message_prompt: 'wright msg'
    });
}
</script>
```

Work only one function not two. how to make two functions work simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be enough:

```
onclick="return onVote(), jsuipopup(), false;"
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/MeTCz/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code exits after onVote() executes, so jsuipopup() is never reached.

Try changing from this:

```
onclick="(return onVote(), function jsuipopup();)"
```

To this:

```
onclick="jsuipopup(); return onVote();"
```

Though for clarity, it may make more sense to have the function definition set to a variable that you can reference:

```
var voteAndStuff = function() { 
   jsuipopup(); 
   return onVote();
}
```

And then just call it like this:

```
onclick="return voteAndStuff();"
```